# Address no longer shows up in Bcoiner account

Tags: wallet, lost-bitcoins

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded Bcoiner on my iPad.
2. Made an account.
3. Generated a new address, which was [1NEuLDXuBRTYfcbGpzUbpkr4Sg2p7sNLB4](https://blockchain.info/address/1NEuLDXuBRTYfcbGpzUbpkr4Sg2p7sNLB4).
4. I sent 4.69 bitcoins to this address.

I logged back into my account an hour or so later. I found that the address which I created earlier above has disappeared. I sent all my coins there.  I can see that they made it to the address but I have no access to them because the address is no longer visible on my account with Bcoiner.

I have emailed support at Bcoiner; they have not replied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately if this is a Bcoiner bug only them can recover your address and your Bitcoin.

When you generate an address, you generate a private key (linked to your bcoiner account) if Bcoiner can't recover it I'm afraid you have lost your bitcoin forever.

The best solution is then to contact them.

Remember : use a local wallet (Bitcoin-qt for example) and make a bakup of your wallet periodically, if you want to use an online service then make a local backup of your wallet to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: Much Appreciated

Comment: Adam, if my answer has resolved your case please mark it as accepted :) You can see how to it here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers